# Is it possible to create a grid in Gimp that is part of the image?

Tags: gimp, grids

I want to make pixel art in Gimp, but the grid that I pull up is only a filter. I'd like to get a perfect fill for each pixel instead of having to measure the pixel and line it up each time. Is it possible to get a grid that can do this? Thanks!

Comment: You should extend the question and describe what you do and why it is not adequate for the task - because the image grid in GIMP should be exactly the thing you want for placing individual pixels accurately.

Answer (score 1):

No grid is needed, use real pixels for pixel art. Define your new image for example to be 60 pixel wide and 40 pixel high. Then draw with 1 pixel wide pencil.

If you want a copy with higher pixel dimensions, make a copy and scale it (Image > Scale). Define interpolation method = None to keep it sharp

Answer (score 0):

*Image → Configure Grid...* and *View → Show grid* or *View → Snap to grid.*

Comment: This answer looks more like a comment. Could we squeeze a little more detail out of you for this question?

Comment: @Stan: Details do not make the difference between comments and answers. Comments are for suggesting improvements to the question (and similar stuff); answers are for solving the asker’s problem.